# How to avoid "Documents and Settings" getting huge with downloadable content

Tags: ios, backup, document, icloud

I got a fix it ticket from Apple.  They seem to be fussy that the Documents and Settings is 36 MB from downloading an accessory.

So we use Amazon to download content... but which directory to put it in?  To avoid Documents and Settings from getting too big.  We tried marking the files as NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey but they still appear in the Documents and Settings.

If "Documents and Settings" is big does that mean it gets backed up?

**How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes**?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html